# Horizontal Roulette/Slot Machine

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

I need to implement a horizontal wheel of fortune in **Angular 1.x** and **Ionic 1.x**.

The idea is, we have a list of cards stacked on top of each other horizontally. The user clicks the spin button and we cycle through the cards like a slot machine or wheel of fortune, with a simple animation of course. The user clicks stop and we slow down to stumble upon a card.

These cards are prize options, each card has a value like 150 points. So I need to shuffle through the list and select the result.

I've been googling around for days and I haven't come across any examples for this. I've found many examples and plugins for implementing a wheel of fortune, slot machine, spin ball etc. But nothing for a horizontal roulette. Any code snippets, plugins or tutorials are much appreciated.

Comment: Create some cards stacked on top of each other to start with. Ask questions for each problem you face. Go on and start it :)

Comment: Start with slot machine code you found. Then read up on `context.setTransform` to make the vertical slots become horizontal. ;-)